# HTML Button Tag Style On Hover

Tags: html, css

I am using the HTML button tag but the style mentioned below should only apply to the top menu rather than the other button tags in the site. I tried using the code `button.menuButton:hover` but it does not work

```
<button id="menuButton" type="button" name="menuButton" title="Logout">
    <img src="images/commonicons/logout.png" alt="Logout" id="imgLogout" /><br /><b>Logout</b>
</button>
```

and applying the below style which will show the bottom border as ridge with Lime color and rest of the sides will be in dashed mode.

```
button:hover {
    border: 1px dashed #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom: 2px ridge Lime;
}
```

Comment: Change button:hover to button#menuButton:hover, it will work fine

Comment: @gout Better yet, just `#menuButton:hover`—since you have an ID, there's no need to give a tag name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the style to be applied to only specific buttons, you should specify a class only in those button tags. for example:
This is the button class:

```
.mybutton
{
    border: 1px dashed #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom: 2px ridge Lime;
}
```

And while declaring the button:

This button will have the style :

```
 <button id="menuButton" type="button" name="menuButton" class="mybutton" title="Logout">
  <img src="images/commonicons/logout.png" alt="Logout" id="imgLogout" /><br       /><b>Logout</b>
</button>
```

This button will not have the style:

```
<button id="menuButton" type="button" name="menuButton"title="Logout">
      <img src="images/commonicons/logout.png" alt="Logout" id="imgLogout" /><br       /><b>Logout</b>
    </button>
```

Comment: boss why both id and class ? either of them is enough.

Comment: @gout : because the asker has used id in his question, I just let it be there.

Comment: @suraj : vidu vidu .. last warning.

Comment: boss :I accept question is format is really bad. very poor standard, this code won't work in non webkit supported browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `button.menuButton:hover` then your button will need the .menuButton class.

```
<button [...] class="menuButton">
```

In CSS the dot (.) indicates that you're refering to a class name on an element.

Comment: @Yashman Gupta : If you want the style to be applied to only specific buttons, you should specify a class only in those button tags. for example: